# Wifi connects but no internet access on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-4, dhcp, raspbian-buster

I can connect my Raspberry Pi 4 to my wifi, but I can't seem to access the internet. I can ping machines on the network, and I can ping (and even VNC into) the Pi from network machines. However, I can't access the internet from the Pi. Please help!

I've included some output below that will hopefully help. I'm happy to provide command outputs as needed. I really appreciate any input you can provide!

```
pi@rasp:~ $ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination   Gateway       Genmask        Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
0.0.0.0       192.168.1.1   0.0.0.0        UG    303    0   0   wlan0
192.168.1.0   0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0  U     303    0   0   wlan0
```

```
pi@rasp:~ $ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

```
pi@rasp:~ $ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

```
pi@rasp:~ $ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by resolvconf
domain Home
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether dc:a6:32:38:12:4f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2126  bytes 698889 (682.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2126  bytes 698889 (682.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.57  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::1b86:80c7:81f7:5cf6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:38:12:50  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3689  bytes 838441 (818.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2013  bytes 299366 (292.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
pi@rasp:~ $ ping 4.2.2.4
PING 4.2.2.24 (4.2.2.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 4.2.2.4: imp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=29.4 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.4: imp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=30.4 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.4: imp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=30.4 ms
...
^C
--- 4.2.2.4 ping statistics ---
16 packets transmitted, 16 received, 0% packet loss, time 39ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 27.547/39.744/131.852/25.332 ms
```

```
pi@rasp:~ $ cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf 
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
# Some non-RFC compliant DHCP servers do not reply with this set.
# In this case, comment out duid and enable clientid above.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# Most distributions have NTP support.
#option ntp_servers

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate SLAAC address using the Hardware Address of the interface
#slaac hwaddr
# OR generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses based from the DUID
slaac private

# Example static IP configuration:
#interface eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
#static ip6_address=fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::ff/64
#static routers=192.168.0.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::1

# It is possible to fall back to a static IP if DHCP fails:
# define static profile
#profile static_eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.1.23/24
#static routers=192.168.1.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1

# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to this community. || If you `ping 4.2.2.4` and it gives you echo reply, comment all lines of `/etc/resolv.conf` and add `nameserver 4.2.2.4`, then add the result to the question.

Comment: Alright, after that, try `ping www.google.com`.

Comment: @M.Rostami Same issue as before ```ping: www.google.com: Name or service not known```

Comment: Ok, so now realized that the name server is not the problem. Additionally, add configuration of this file `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` to the question. It would help the experts to deduce what's the problem.

Comment: @M.Rostami Added.

Comment: Are you sure after adding `nameserver 4.2.2.4` to `/etc/resolv.conf`, didn't you restart network services? If any network services restart, the setting would be restarted, too. Your route is true. Try this one: add `static domain_name_servers=4.2.2.4 8.8.8.8` at the end of the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and reboot the device (not necessary, if you can, do it.). Then, make sure that `nameserver 4.2.2.4` or `nameserver 8.8.8.8` has added to `/etc/resolv.conf`. || in addition, as your second comment, you add `name server 4.2.2.4` instead of `nameserver 4.2.2.4`. Maybe the problem is with this mistake.

Comment: @M.Rostami I rebooted after adding ```nameserver 4.2.2.4``` to ```/etc/resolv.conf```. And rebooted the device again after adding ```static domain_name_servers=4.2.2.4 8.8.8.8``` at the end of the ```/etc/dhcpcd.conf```. Still not successful.

Comment: Alright, you can comment this line. There is a lot of possibilities in this case. Check [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=31238) out.

Comment: @M.Rostami Reverted. I worked through the link, but nothing recommended there did the trick.

Comment: Your DNS server @ 192.168.1.1 isn't working. Try updating /etc/resolv.conf with `nameserver 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Does this work ? `ping -4 www.google.com` (to make sure the name is not resolved to an IPv6 address)

Comment: @Dougie I've updated the /etc/resolv.conf with ```nameserver 8.8.8.8``` and rebooted. Didn't work.
@Anonymous Pinging google with -4 resulted in ```Name or service not found```

Comment: That was a temporary fix until you reboot. You need to sort out your home router so that it passes the right nameserver address when a device connects.

Answer (score 0):

After a ton of time spent Google and StackExchange searching, I wasn't able to solve the issue. So I just resorted to wiping and reinstalling the OS from scratch. It works.

Comment: Please mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as a unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the edit connections and go to the wifi and click on the settings icon and got to general and put the priority to -999 which will start the wifi service as soon as the raspberry pi starts.